# How to set text box width in wysihtml5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, wysihtml5

I am trying to implement [wysihtml5](http://jhollingworth.github.io/bootstrap-wysihtml5/) in a bootstrap from But the width of the text are appears to be be small ,I tried cols  attribute, but didn't work[image]

Comment: The editor loads in an iframe. The iframe gets its width from its parent container. So set the width of the parent (where you put the textarea) or look for css rules for iframes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just set a width of the actual textarea

```
textarea#my_id { width: 100% }
```